# how to pass PHP variable to processing.js

Tags: javascript, php, processing.js

Hi i need a way to pass PHP value to processing.js how can i do this. I know that i got to use AJAX but i don't know what to do to recive value in processing.js. I've tryed something like that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function go(){
        var s;
    var variable = 5;
    $.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        tupe:"POST",
        url: "take.php",
        data:({val:variable}),
        success: function(data){
            //$('#msg').html(data);  
                            var b = data;
                            s=b;
        }

    });
            alert (s);
    }
</script>
```

and my PHP is:

```
<?php
if($_POST){
    $img = "index.jpg"  ;
    echo $img;

}
?>
```

but when i alert '**s**' it is undefined and i dont know how to pass it to processing code to show image in to a canvas. Can someone felp me?

Comment: A better practice would be to output in JSON format from PHP.

Comment: Your alert is running before the response is received. You need to put it in the success callback if you want to use the value returned in the response.

Answer (score 2):

Ajax is asynchronous. That means that while the ajax call executes, the script continues.

Your `s` variable is not defined until after the ajax call finishes, in the `success` function. Right after the ajax call in the script - but not in time -  it is not defined yet.

To access the variables returned by the ajax call, you need to put your logic in the `success` function.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is correct, but another option is to use a **synchronous** call, which will block the call to `ajax()` until the data returns. This is how it looks like you assumed it worked.

To make a synchronous call, just pass the `async:false` parameter into the `ajax()` call, like this:

```
$.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        tupe:"POST",
        url: "take.php",
        data:({val:variable}),
        success: function(data){
            //$('#msg').html(data);  
                            var b = data;
                            s=b;
        },
        async: false
    });
```

More info here: [How can I get jQuery to perform a synchronous, rather than asynchronous, Ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re)

And in the [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).